# php text file to array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, split, arrayofarrays

i got a text file that contains

```
a b c 

a c

b
```

i want to read the text file and convert it to array of arrays like this

```
  array(
        array('a', 'b', 'c'),
        array('a', 'c'),
        array('b'));
```

i want to split each line in an array and each word in a index in the array

i tried this code but it only split each line in a array i want each word in a array of the line

```
$file="140724.txt";
$fopen = fopen($file, r);
$fread = fread($fopen,filesize($file));
fclose($fopen);
$remove = "\n";
$split = explode($remove, $fread);
$array[] = null;
$tab = "\t";
foreach ($split as $string)
{
    $row = explode($tab, $string);
    array_push($array,$row);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

i got this result

```
Array

(

    [0] => 

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a b c
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a b
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        ))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the code quite a bit by using some of the inbuilt functions.

Using [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) with the appropriate flags will read the file in, ignoring any empty lines and return an array of data.

Then use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) along with `explode()` to process this array and split it into the individual parts per row...

```
$fileName = "140724.txt";
$file = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
$output = array_map(function($line) { return explode("\t", $line); }, $file);
```

will produce

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => c
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with like this.

```
$file="140724.txt";
$fopen = fopen($file, r);
$fread = fread($fopen,filesize($file));
fclose($fopen);
$remove = "\n";
$split = explode($remove, $fread);
$array = array();
$tab = " ";
foreach ($split as $string)
{
    $array[] = explode($tab, $string);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this help to you.

Comment: This code may work but it doesn't explain the issues in the OP code...

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of errors.

First - init the `$array` var as `$array = [];` and not `$array[] = null;`.

Second, you can use [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) which will be better.

Last, I think the delimiter is  (white space) and not `\t`.

Consider:

```
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, " ")) !== FALSE) {
    $arr[] = $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give perfect output without blank array.Thank me later.

```
$file="140724.txt";
$fopen = fopen($file, 'r');
$fread = fread($fopen,filesize($file));
fclose($fopen);
$remove = "\n";
$split = explode($remove, $fread);

$custom_array = array();
$x = 0;
foreach ($split as $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if($value != '' || $value != null){
        $inside_explode = explode(" ", $value);
        $custom_array[$x] = $inside_explode;
        $x++;
    }


}
print_r($custom_array);
```

Comment: This code may work but it doesn't explain the issues in the OP code...

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileData = file('1.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$result = [];
foreach ($fileData as $row) {
    $splitRow = str_getcsv($row, ' ');
    $result[] = $splitRow;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

```
$fileData = file('1.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$result = array_map(function ($row) {
    return str_getcsv($row, ' ');
}, $fileData);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it